# Flask display user register, or already login in every template of each module

Tags: python, flask

I'm learning flask and im up to the blueprint section. First of all, i have the header.html which is included by base.html, and the route for index is below:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template("index.html", is_auth=session[is_authenticated], username=session[username])
```

header.html:

```
{% if is_auth %}
    Welcome {{ username }}</font>,
{% else %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('users.register') }}"> Register / Login</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

base.html is simple:

```
{% block header %}
{% include 'header.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}  

{% block footer %}
{% include 'footer.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Everything works fine, the header will ask to register if not logged in, otherwise display "Welcome...".

My problem is that i'm using blueprints for 2 modules which are "users" and "books" so they have 2 following subdir: */users/* and */books/*. For each module it will extend the 'content' block from base.html

However, the thing is that if I have a route for either profile, rank, logout etc ... I then need to send out the session[is_authenticated] and session[username] to the template in order to display the header correctly. What I mean is like:

```
@mod.route('/profile/')
@requires_login
def profile():
  # do something here
  return render_template("users/profile.html", is_auth=session[is_authenticated], username=session[username])

@mod.route('/rank/')
@requires_login
def rank():
  # do something here
  return render_template("users/rank.html", is_auth=session[is_authenticated], username=session[username])

@mod.route('/register/')
def register():
  # do something here
  return render_template("users/register.html", form=forms, is_auth=session[is_authenticated], username=session[username])
```

The code is very redundant because I have to send out same thing over and over again. Are there any efficient ways or better way to deal with this problem?

Thank you so much and have a nice daY!

Comment: What authentication system are you using? You should just be able to do `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` in your template without adding anything to `render_template`.

Comment: i dont use any, i just basically save the info to the database and keep the session

Comment: Using something well-tested like [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is going to be safer and easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like you should use `flask-login` to make your life easier. if you look on the github, you'll see that they do what you're trying to do already

```
:param add_context_processor: Whether to add a context processor to
  the app that adds a `current_user` variable to the template.
  Defaults to ``True``.
```

Quick version of getting it set up for your purposes:

start by initializing flask-login on your app

```
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
login_manager = LoginManager()

def create_app(config=None):
  # ...
  login_manager.init_app(app)
  return app
```

then, add a `user_loader` in your models, or wherever your model of a user is

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

then, on your login view, you can simply add a few lines to grab the user and use `flask-login`'s `login_user` function. This example assumes it came in from a WTForm and uses the form's data and SQLAlchemy. `User` is my model. Very basic example.

```
from ..models import User
# ...
u = User.query.filter_by(email=form.name.data).first()
if u is not None:
  login_user(u)
```

on your templates, there will be a global for `current_user` with flask-login. you can simply use `{{ current_user.is_authenticated }}` to check if the current user is there.

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
  <h1>Hi, {{ current_user.username }}</h1>
{% else %}
  <a href="{{ url_for(user.login) }}">why aren't you logged in?</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thank for your answer, in the purpose of learning i just wanted to know an alternate way to solve it :D thnks again